# How to make a iOS App which only runs for e.g. 1 Day?

Tags: ios

how can I make something in my app like:

After the first start of the App, it can only be used for e.g. 24h?

I need to make a inhouse distribution and just want the people to use my app for only 24h

Comment: What about just storing the date in the NSUserDefaults and then after 24 hour make the app unusable as an initial state?

Comment: Problem is that I want to use a cordova app

Comment: What is the problem with Cordova? Are you asking how you should get the current date in Cordova? Or are you asking how you should save the end date? You're getting a lot of down votes, so maybe you should try to clarify your question more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

USE ONLY IF YOU WANT TO USE IT AS INHOUSE APP.

Write following code in `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions` method

```
if (![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:IS_APP_RUNNING_FIRST_TIME])
{
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSDate date] forKey:IS_APP_RUNNING_FIRST_TIME];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}
else
{
    NSDate * firstDate = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:IS_APP_RUNNING_FIRST_TIME];
    NSDate * todayDate = [NSDate date];

    NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc]
                             initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];

    NSUInteger unitFlags = NSHourCalendarUnit;

    NSDateComponents *components = [gregorian components:unitFlags
                                                fromDate:firstDate
                                                  toDate:todayDate options:0];
    NSInteger hours = [components hour];
    if (hours>24)
    {
        // Apple can reject exit(0);
        //USE ONLY IF YOU WANT TO USE IT AS INHOUSE APP
        exit(0); 
    }
}
```

Comment: apple not allow  `exit(0);` application going to be reject by iTunes connect. this answer is not fully suitable.

Comment: Question has information that he wants to use it as inhouse distribution.

Comment: and now imagine, that your app crashed every time (tnx exit(0)) - it is NOT user friendly.

Comment: A better experience would be to show a fullscreen view controller that informs the user that the use of the app has expired and direct them to some admin within the enterprise group whom they can contact if they need to continue using the app.

Comment: This is really easy to subvert, consider how important it is to prevent them from using the app for longer than 24 hours.